# PHP security check - Cross-Site Scripting: Reflected

Tags: php, xss, fortify

Fortify Audit Workbench always generating error on Get and echo. Adding their report below. how to overcome this?

Set I

```
offroad.php, line 75 (Cross-Site Scripting: Reflected) Critical
Issue Details
Kingdom: Input Validation and Representation
Scan Engine: SCA (Data Flow)
Source Details
Source: Read $_GET['id']
File: offroad.php:6

if(ctype_alnum(str_replace($aValid, '', addslashes($_GET['id'])))) // Allow
alphanumeric and only underscore
{
$id=addslashes(($_GET['id']));
```

Set II

```
Cross-Site Scripting: Reflected Critical
Package: <none>
offroad.php, line 75 (Cross-Site Scripting: Reflected) Critical
Sink Details
Sink: builtin_echo()
File: offroad.php:75
Taint Flags: SQLI_POORVALIDATION, WEB, XSS

<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="centre" width="45%">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value='<?php echo base64_encode($id);?>'/>
<input type="submit" value="Go To Location" class="button-9" role="button">
</td></td></tr>
</table>
```

This is a auditing report. The two mentioned issue, how to solve it?

Comment: In Set II I expect they want you to HTML-encode the output into that HTML snippet. But you're already base64-encoding it, so it ought to be ok I _think_. Although I'm not sure why you're base64-encoding it - any particular reason?

Comment: It's unclear why the Set I code was flagged for XSS. However, I would like to make a point about that code: What do you imagine that `addslashes` is achieving in that code? It rarely, if ever, does anything useful. That smells to me like either ancient code which needs a thorough review, or some cargo-cult programming (i.e. rote usage of a function without understanding why.)

Comment: it already checking the validation 
$aValid = array('_');
if(ctype_alnum(str_replace($aValid, '', addslashes($_GET['id']))))  // Allow alphanumeric and only underscore
{
So, addslashes not much required. but the report of error on GET

Comment: `So, addslashes not much required`...you should remove it then, it is likely doing more harm than good.

Comment: `the report of error on GET`...I know. And as I said, it's unclear to me why this has been flagged.  XSS is not a risk during input of data (it's only a potential problem when outputting user-generated content into a HTML document). I suggest asking the makers of the software why it would flag this, and/or consulting the product documentation to see if there is a more detailed explanation of the conditions under which this type of flag is issued, and any suggested mitigation. Otherwise I would sugggest you can simply ignore the warning as a false-flag. These programs are not perfect.

Comment: Thanks ADyson. But with out passing the file through the audit they will not allow to put on server. This is my issue.

Comment: Well the auditors need to understand that this software is not perfect, and will sometimes flag items incorrectly. Some flexibility should be given, in cases where the programmer can demonstrate that there isn't a real issue. There is no logical way to prevent XSS in the Set I case. XSS is not a direct threat in that situation.

Comment: Having said that, I am not experienced in  interpreting the format of this specific type of report, but the fact that both of the entries mention `offroad.php, line 75` is interesting. I assume line 75 is `<input type="hidden" name="id" value='<?php echo base64_encode($id);?>'/>`? I wonder if Set I is actually just warning you that this `$_GET["id"]` is being used later in the script, in a way which _could_ be vulnerable to XSS. It's not saying there's a problem on line 6 necessarily.

Comment: Therefore, if you resolve Set II it may make the Set I error disappear at the same time. As I said earlier, is there a particular reason why you are using `base64_encode()` there? Using `htmlspecialchars()` would normally be used to prevent XSS in that scenario. And I can't see an obvious benefit to base64-encoding your ID. Can you clarify the intention of that use of base64_encode()?

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. We explained the code and flow to the auditor and they agree to skip these errors.  They also saying the testing tool is not fully correct.